# Not able to access cert in Local Service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am not able to acess a cert when deploying my application in service fabric local cluster `topologyConfigurationManager = new TopologyConfigurationManager(new Uri("https://int2.metrics.nsatc.net"), GenevaCertThumbprint, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));`

**StoreLocation.LocalMachine** The cert is present in my local machine.

Comment: does `NETWORK SERVICE` account have access to read it